# CompletableFuture on ParallelStream gets batched and runs slower than sequential stream?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream, completable-future

**Method 1**

The usual, very fast, and works great.

```java
public static int loops = 500;
private static ExecutorService customPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(loops);
.
.
Instant start = Instant.now();
LongSummaryStatistics stats = LongStream.range(0, loops).boxed()
        .map(number -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> DummyProcess.slowNetworkCall(number), customPool))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()).stream() // collect first, else will be sequential
        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
        .mapToLong(Long::longValue)
        .summaryStatistics();

log.info("cf completed in :: {}, summaryStats :: {} ", Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).toMillis(), stats);
// ... cf completed in :: 1054, summaryStats :: LongSummaryStatistics{count=500, sum=504008, min=1000, average=1008.016000, max=1017}
```

I understand that if I don't collect the stream first, then by nature of laziness, the stream will spring up CompletableFutures one by one, and behave synchronously. *So, as an experiment:*

**Method 2**

Remove the intermediate collect step, **but make the stream parallel also!** :

```java
Instant start = Instant.now();
LongSummaryStatistics stats = LongStream.range(0, loops).boxed()
        .parallel()
        .map(number -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> DummyProcess.slowNetworkCall(number), customPool))
        .map(CompletableFuture::join) // direct join
        .mapToLong(Long::longValue).summaryStatistics();

log.info("cfps_directJoin completed in :: {}, summaryStats :: {} ", Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).toMillis(), stats);
// ... cfps_directJoin completed in :: 8098, summaryStats :: LongSummaryStatistics{count=500, sum=505002, min=1000, average=1010.004000, max=1015}
```

**Summary:**

- Method 1 :: **1 second**
- Method 2 :: **8 seconds**

**A pattern I observed:**

1. the parallelstream approach "batches" 60 calls at onces, so with 500 loops, 500/60 ~ 8 batches, each taking 1 second, thus total 8
2. SO, when I reduce the loop count to 300, there are 300/60 = 5 batches, and it takes 5 seconds to complete actually.

#### So, the question is:

Why is there this batching of calls in the parallel + direct collection approach?

---

For completion, here's my dummy network call method:

```java
    public static Long slowNetworkCall(Long i) {
        Instant start = Instant.now();
        log.info(" {} going to sleep..", i);
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(1000); // 1 second
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        log.info(" {} woke up..", i);
        return Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).toMillis();
    }
```

Comment: good question. I wonder if this is an artifact of an internal implementation detail of `ForkJoinPool` when threads (above configured parallelism) are blocked. Essentially your `.map(CompletableFuture::join)` will block a `ForJoinPool` thread, and at that time a new one will be spawned to support the configured parallelism. This might (I am not sure) cause somehow the behavior you experience.

Comment: You could try to use your own thread pool.

Comment: yeah, I am more convinced this is "just" the way `ForJoinPool` behaves for when you block its threads. Just run your code with `-Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=50` for example; on my machine it finishes in 2 seconds (so it's not "batching" to `8` always) I wish I could tell you where that computation happens _exactly_ in the `ForkJoinPool`, but that code is insanely complicated.

Comment: OK, I _think_ I have a hint. If you log `ForkJoinPool.commonPool().getPoolSize()` at each operation, you will see that it is (after you start blocking) constantly staying at `64`, which, as far as I understand, is the maximum number of threads that can work at a time. So that looks on par with the results that you see. I am not exactly sure this can count as an answer, though.

Comment: @Eugene put a followup question, after trying some variations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67416858/forkjoinpool-size-increasing-dynamically

Comment: The results will likely change depending on what is in that `slowNetworkCall`.  You might try putting in actual IO, or a busy loop.  Also, invoking logging might create sync points, which would affect the result.  Finally, a second is a very long time in current systems.  A smaller sleep time might more realistic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an artifact of how `ForJoinPool` handles things when you block its inner threads, and how many new ones it spawns. Though, I could probably find the exact lines where this happens, I am not sure it is worth it. For two reasons:

- that logic can change
- the code inside `ForkJoinPool` is by far not trivial

It seems that for both of us, `ForkJoinPool.commonPool().getParallelism()` will return `11`, so I get the same results as you do. If you log `ForkJoinPool.commonPool().getPoolSize()` to find out how many active threads is your code using, you will see that after a certain period, it just stabilizes itself at `64`. So the max tasks that can be processed at the same time is `64`, which is on par with the result that you see (those `8 seconds`).

If I run your code with `-Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=50`, it is now executed in `2 seconds`, and the pool size is increased to `256`. That means, there is an internal logic that adjusts these kind of things.