# ForkJoinPool size increasing dynamically?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-stream, forkjoinpool

Related: [CompletableFuture on ParallelStream gets batched and runs slower than sequential stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67411386/2715083)

I'm doing some research on different ways of parallelizing network calls through parallelStream and CompletableFutures. As such, I have come across this situation where the ForkJoinPool.commonPool(), which is used by java's parallelStream, is dynamically growing in size, from ~ #Cores, to Max value of 64.

Java details:
`$ java -version`

```
openjdk version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.10+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.10+9, mixed mode)
```

Code that shows such behavior is below (Full executable code [here](https://github.com/Suedo/AlgoDS/blob/f7e4fd367c7ecb4ca2d2ba9ff9cb266a46c78b89/src/main/java/generalworks/parallelism/DummyProcess.java))

```java
    public static int loops = 100;
    private static long sleepTimeMs = 1000;
    private static ExecutorService customPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(loops);




    // this method shows dynamic increase in pool size
    public static void m1() {
        Instant start = Instant.now();
        LongSummaryStatistics stats = LongStream.range(0, loops).boxed()
                .parallel()
                .map(number -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                        () -> DummyProcess.slowNetworkCall(number), customPool))
                .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                .mapToLong(Long::longValue)
                .summaryStatistics();

    }

    // this method shows static pool size
    public static void m2() {
        Instant start = Instant.now();
        LongSummaryStatistics stats = LongStream.range(0, loops)
                .parallel()
                .map(DummyProcess::slowNetworkCall) // in this call, parallelism/poolsize stays constant 11
                .summaryStatistics();
    }


    public static Long slowNetworkCall(Long i) {
        Instant start = Instant.now();
        // starts with 11 (#cores in my laptop = 12), goes upto 64
        log.info(" {} going to sleep. poolsize: {}", i, ForkJoinPool.commonPool().getPoolSize());
        try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        log.info(" {} woke up..", i);
        return Duration.between(start, Instant.now()).toMillis();
    }
```

Sample output:

```
16:07:17.443 [pool-2-thread-7] INFO  generalworks.parallelism.DummyProcess -  44 going to sleep. poolsize: 11
16:07:17.443 [pool-2-thread-9] INFO  generalworks.parallelism.DummyProcess -  7 going to sleep. poolsize: 12
16:07:17.443 [pool-2-thread-4] INFO  generalworks.parallelism.DummyProcess -  6 going to sleep. poolsize: 12
16:07:17.444 [pool-2-thread-13] INFO  generalworks.parallelism.DummyProcess -  82 going to sleep. poolsize: 13
16:07:17.444 [pool-2-thread-14] INFO  generalworks.parallelism.DummyProcess -  26 going to sleep. poolsize: 14
16:07:17.444 [pool-2-thread-15] INFO  generalworks.parallelism.DummyProcess -  96 going to sleep. poolsize: 15
16:07:17.445 [pool-2-thread-16] INFO  generalworks.parallelism.DummyProcess -  78 going to sleep. poolsize: 16
.
.
16:07:18.460 [pool-2-thread-79] INFO  generalworks.parallelism.DummyProcess -  2 going to sleep. poolsize: 64
16:07:18.460 [pool-2-thread-71] INFO  generalworks.parallelism.DummyProcess -  36 going to sleep. poolsize: 64
16:07:18.460 [pool-2-thread-74] INFO  generalworks.parallelism.DummyProcess -  77 going to sleep. poolsize: 64
16:07:18.461 [pool-2-thread-83] INFO  generalworks.parallelism.DummyProcess -  86 going to sleep. poolsize: 64
```

I understand that the number of Threads in a commonpool, i.e, it `parallelism` is based upon max number of available cores, so since my laptop has 12 cores, i get a parallelism of 11 to start with. But I do not understand why it keeps climbing in one method, but in the other one, it's size keeps constants

Comment: It's not really obvious what the output corresponds to. You have different fragments of code but nothing we can actually run. Give us the complete test case.

Comment: @Michael here's the complete code:
https://github.com/Suedo/AlgoDS/blob/f7e4fd367c7ecb4ca2d2ba9ff9cb266a46c78b89/src/main/java/generalworks/parallelism/DummyProcess.java

Comment: what do you mean exactly with : "Especially when a a slight variation of the same...". You need to provide full, understandable example in your question itself. I for example, did not understand anything from that sentence.

Comment: the part "But I do not understand why it keeps climbing" - I already addressed in the other questions comments. When you _block_ an inner threads that `ForkJoinPool` uses (and you _do_ that with `CompletableFuture::join`), more threads will be created to compensate, so that target parallelism stays correct.

Comment: @Eugene ok, so in method1, due to join, its causing the poolsize to increase, but since no such join is in method 2, the poolsize stays same. I guess that solves it, didnt notice earlier. You can frame that in as an answer, and we can close this question as resolved

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe your answer is [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/1ddf9a99e4ad/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.java#l1558) (`ForkJoinPool` implementation):

```
                        if ((wt = q.owner) != null &&
                            ((ts = wt.getState()) == Thread.State.BLOCKED ||
                             ts == Thread.State.WAITING))
                            ++bc;            // worker is blocking
```

In one version of your code, you block on `Thread.sleep`, which puts the thread into the `TIMED_WAITING` state, while in the other you block on `CompletableFuture.join()`, which puts it into the `WAITING` state. The implementation distinguishes between these and exhibits the different behaviors you have observed.

There is also special-cased code inside `CompletableFuture` that makes it cooperate with the `ForkJoinPool` in order to prevent starvation while waiting for the result:

```
            if (Thread.currentThread() instanceof ForkJoinWorkerThread)
                ForkJoinPool.helpAsyncBlocker(defaultExecutor(), q);
```

A conclusion relevant to the reason why you're testing this in the first place: `Thread.sleep()` does not properly simulate a long network call. If you did an actual one, or some other blocking operation, it would compensate by extending the pool.

Answer (score 3):

The provided answer is absolutely correct. According to the documentation of `ForJoinPool::getPoolSize`:

> The result returned by this method may differ from `getParallelism()` when threads are created to maintain parallelism when others are **cooperatively blocked**.

As you have seen, `sleep` does not count as *cooperatively blocked* (I guess it sort of makes sense). You can read a somehow related [Q&A, here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65753436/how-to-efficiently-use-completablefuture-to-map-async-task-per-input/65768653#65768653)